# When does a matrix have an "invariant quadratic form"?

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, integer-lattices

Yesterday I computed that the matrix

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

satisfies $q(m,n) = q \left((m,n)A\right)$ for the quadratic form

$$q(m,n) = m^2 - mn - n^2.$$

E.g., $-1 = q(1,1) = q(3,2) = q(8,5) =\ \ldots\ $ which is quite satisfying.

On the other hand, the matrix

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

fixes no such quadratic form, although it does preserve $(m,n)\mapsto (q(m,n))^2$ (since $B^2 = A$ this is maybe unsurprising).

**My question.** Is it known when a square matrix with integer entries preserves a non-trivial quadratic form? Moreover, when does such a quadratic form have integer coefficients?

It seems easy to verify for individual examples, but is there a general theory?

Comment: I don't know much about integral quadratic forms, but assuming your quadratic form is represented by a symmetric matrix $G$ as $q(v) = v G v^t$ then a square matrix $A$ preserves $q$ if $q(vA) = (vA) G (vA)^t = v (AGA^t) v^t = q(v) = v G v^t$  which happens iff $AGA^t = G$. Given $A$, this is a homogeneous system of equations for $G$ and it might or might not have non-trivial symmetric solutions depending on the structure of $A$. For $A$ the system of solutions is one dimensional (over $\mathbb{Q}$) and spanned by the quadratic form you found but for $B$ the system has no solutions.

Comment: @levap: thanks! You've uncovered the secret method I used to calculate this. Your reward is a degenerate example:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1  \end{pmatrix} \longleftrightarrow (m,n)\mapsto n^2$$

Comment: If you write down the system of equations for the $2 \times 2$ case you get three equations in three variables (the entries of $G$). Brute forcing it, somewhat surprisingly you get that this system has a non-zero solution iff $\det(A) = 1$ or $\det(A) = \textrm{trace}(A) - 1$ or $\det(A) = -\textrm{trace}(A) - 1$. Writing the equations in terms of eigenvalues shows you that you have a non-trivial quadratic form iff the eigenvalues of $A$ are of the form $x,\frac{1}{x}$ or $\pm 1, x$.

Comment: @levap Indeed, Mathematica agrees with you! Cool stuff.

Comment: @levap In fact, you may be interested to know, according to some faffing, in three dimensions, it seems $A$ has an invariant non-trivial quadratic form iff its eigenvalues $(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$ satisfy the equation $$\left (\lambda^2 - 1 \right)\left (\mu^2 - 1 \right)\left (\nu^2 - 1 \right) (\lambda\mu - 1) (\lambda \nu - 1) (\mu \nu - 1) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for these answers. Prompted by the $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ case, the following is apparent.

**Proposition.**

$A \in \mathbb R^{n,n}$ fixes a non-trivial quadratic form if and only if

$$
1 \in \left(\sigma(A)\right)^2 := \left\{\lambda \mu\,|\,\lambda,\mu \in \sigma(A)\right\},
$$

where $\sigma(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C\,|\,\lambda\text{ is an eigenvalue of }A\}$.

*I.e.,* either $\pm1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, or there is some $\lambda\neq 0$ s.t. $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{-1}$ are both eigenvalues of $A$

*Proof*.

($1$): First, if $\lambda,\mu \in \sigma(A)$ satisfy $\lambda\mu=1$, then (letting $A^Tv = \lambda v$, $A^Tw = \lambda w$) $A$ preserves the quadratic form given by the matrix $Q = vw^T \in \mathbb R^{n,n}$ (with respect to standard basis on $\mathbb R$):
$$
A^TQA = (A^Tv)(A^Tw)^T = \lambda\mu\, vw^T = vw^T = Q.
$$
Moreover, $Q$ cannot be skew-symmetric, so defines a non-trivial quadratic form: the $(i,j)$th entry of $Q$, $Q_{i,j} =v_iw_j$ is non-zero for at least one $i,j$. If $i=j$ then we're done, so assume that thee exists $i\neq j$ with $v_iw_j\neq0$; and assume also that $v_jw_i + v_iw_j = 0$ (for skew-symmetry). This implies that either $v_iw_i\neq 0$ or $v_jw_j\neq 0$ by the following lemma, so we have a non-zero diagonal entry.

---

> **Lemma.** If $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb R$ satisfy $$ ab + cd = 0, \quad ac = 0,\quad bd =0, $$ then $(a,b,c,d)=(0,0,0,0)$.
>
> *Proof of lemma:*
>
> Just multiply the first equation by $ad$ and $bc$, you get $a^2 + d^2=0$, and $b^2 + c^2 = 0$ respectively.

---

($2$) Conversely, suppose that $Q\in \mathbb R^{n,n}$ is symmetric and non-zero, and that $A$ preserves the quadratic form associated to $Q$. Then $$A^TQA = Q$$ (this must hold since the LHS is also symmetric).

Enumerating the elements above the diagonal of $Q$ by $(q_1,\ldots,q_{N})$, where $N = n(n+1)/2$, the previous equation is equivalent to the following.
$$
B\begin{pmatrix}q_1\\\vdots\\q_N\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $B$ is an $N\times N$ matrix whose entries are quadratic expressions in the entries of A: $(A_{i,j})_{i,j}$. In this light, $Q$ is non-trivial is the vector $(q_1,\ldots,q_N)$ is non-zero, i.e. $B$ is singular:
$$\det(B) = 0.$$
This is a degree $2N$-polynomial in $A_{i,j}$. now consider the following equation. Let $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$. There exists a pair of eigenvalues which multiply to one is equivalent to the equation
$$
\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n }\left(\lambda_i\lambda_j - 1\right) = 0.
$$
Now, the left hand side is a symmetric degree-$N$ polynomial in $(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n)$, therefore, by [the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), it is can be expressed in terms of the following:
$$
\left(1,\sum_i \lambda_i, \ \sum_{i<j}\lambda_i\lambda_j,\ \sum_{i<j<k}\lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k,\ \ldots\ , \ \lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n\right);
$$
That is, the equation above is a linear combination of multiples-of-polynomials from this list.) Magically, these also all appear as coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Considering this, each polynomial in this list can be replaced by a homogeneous polynomial in $A_{i,j}$'s *of the same degree*.

Therefore the above degree $N$ polynomial in $\lambda_i$ can be written as a (monstrous) degree $N$ polynomial in the entries $A_{i,j}$, and this polynomial must be a factor of $\det(B)$, since by the first case it is sufficient to have some $\lambda_i\lambda_j=1$ to have $\det(B)=0$. But then they have the same degree ($N$), so $\det(B)$ cannot have any other non-scalar factors. Thus, the eigenvalue condition is actually sufficient. $\square$

**Remark.**

Mote that quadratic forms which are fixed by $A$ in fact form a vector space.

**Extension.**

From the above, my guess is that $A$ fixes a non-degenerate quadratic form if and only if $\{\lambda \in \sigma(A)\,|\,1 \in \lambda\cdot\sigma(A)\} = \sigma(A)$, i.e. all eigenvalues are involved. Equivalently, whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $\lambda \neq 0$ and $1/\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$. Moreover, its Jordan normal form should be a diagonal matrix. Is this sufficient? I'm not sure.

Comment: Be careful that the quadratic forms you define have a tendency to be very degenerate (but maybe you don't mind that, I don't know). For instance the quadratic form you define in $(1)$ has rank $1$.

Comment: That's fine for now: it is curious to see what conditions characterise non-degeneracy (see the extension for my current conjecture). Do you think this should be posed as a distinct MSE question?

Comment: Well it's your question, so you can decide, but in my opinion being an isometry for a rank $1$ quadratic form is really not a very interesting property.

Comment: I mean, you have to start somewhere, right? To clarify: my motivation is dynamical, so degeneracy doesn't make a difference to me. As for the non-degenerate question, it's definitely harder because Jordan blocks can interact with each other: e.g. $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\oplus\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ fixes $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto ad - bc.$, but in general it can certainly be reduced to a question about the Jordan Canonical form for $A$, so its still a a kind of spectral property.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give a partial answer: when $A$ is symmetric a nondegenerate form $q$ with integer coefficients can be constructed if and only if $A$ has determinant $1$, or it is diagonal with eigenvalues $\pm 1$.

Let $Q$ be the matrix defining your quadratic form, in your example

$$Q = \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1/2\\-1/2&-1\end{pmatrix},$$

meaning that

$$q(v) = v^T Q v$$

if we write $v = \begin{pmatrix} m\\n\end{pmatrix}$.

This matrix will always be symmetric, and the quadratic form will have integer coefficients if the off-diagonal elements are half-integers, and the diagonal elements are integers.

In this notation, your question comes down to: given a matrix $A$ over the integers, can I find a matrix $Q$ such that the associated binary form $q$ has integer coefficients, and $q(Av) = q(v)$, which is the case when $A^TQA = Q$.

Note that this is a linear system in the coefficients of $Q$, hence $Q$, if it has solutions, has rational solutions, hence can be scaled to define a form with integer coefficients.

By taking determinants, you immediately see that $A$ must have determinant $\pm 1$, except possibly when $q$ is degenerate. Let's assume it is non-degenerate, so $Q$ is invertible, and we have to find out when it can hold that

$$QA^{-1}Q^{-1} = A^T$$

This says that $A^{-1}$ and $A^T$ are similar, which is a strong condition.

Let's first consider the case that $A$ is symmetric, like in your examples. Then $A$ is diagonalizable by an (orthogonal) matrix $S$: $A = S^{-1}DS = A^T$ for a diagonal matrix $D$, and we have

$$A^{-1} = S^{-1}D^{-1}S, \ \ \ \ A = A^T = S^{-1}DS,$$

The eigenvalues are of the form $\lambda, \pm\lambda^{-1}$ (because the determinant is $\pm 1$). $A^T$ has the same eigenvalues, and $A^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda^{-1}, \mu^{-1} = \pm\lambda$, again the same eigenvalues, possibly up to a sign.

Consider the case that $\det(A) = 1$. In this case either $D^{-1} = D$, or $D^{-1} = P^{-1}DP$, where $P$ is the permutation matrix

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

In the first case $A$ is $\pm1$ and preserves every form, in the second we can take $Q$ to be a suitable multiple of $S^{-1}PS$.

When the determinant is -1, the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ being equal means that $\{\lambda, -\lambda^{-1}\}$ has to be equal to $\{\lambda^{-1}, -\lambda\}$. This is only possible when $\lambda = 1$, and then $D^{-1} = D$ and $A^{-1} = A$, and since $A\ne\pm I$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must be $X^2 - 1$ (by [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)).

That means that $A$ must be traceless, hence of the form

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\b&-a\end{pmatrix}$$

with $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. This leaves multiples of

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

and of

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

as the only possibilities, and they should preserve the binary form given by the identity matrix, $q(m,n) = m^2 + n^2$, which indeed they do.

I'll edit later if I can think of a way to approach the general case.

Comment: Thanks! Is the $\det(A) = -1$ case not more complicated (since, for my non-example above, $\det(B) = -1$)?

Comment: There must be some error because in the non-example $\det(B) = -1$... If my calculations are correct, $A$ (not necessarily symmetric) preserves a non-trivial quadratic form iff $\det(A) = 1$ or $A$ has $1$ or $-1$ as an eigenvalue. This is at least consistent with the two examples.

Comment: It seems that for $A$ symmetric of arbitrary size, $\det(A) = 1$, is it not sufficient for all eigenvalues of $A$ not equal to $\pm1$ to appear in pairs of the form $\{\lambda,\lambda^{-1}\}$?

Comment: @levap: If I am correct in thinking $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$, then it is certainly necessary that $\det(A)^2 = 1$ in order for $A$ to preserve a non-degenerate form: this follows from $A^TQA = Q$. As you rightly point out, $\det(A) = -1$ is not sufficient,

Comment: @levap: Also, the degenerate example (a Jordan block) I commented with above provides a counterexample to your claim (it has determinant $1$ _and_ $1$ as an eigenvalue!).

Comment: @GoodBoy: Doesn't is support my claim? The matrix $A$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue and it preserves a non-trivial quadratic form. Or are you interested only in non-degenerate forms?

Comment: @levap Ah, I see! Sorry, I conflated non-degenerate with non-trivial. I presume you are thinking in two dimensions: consider $-I_3$, where $I_3$ is the $3\times3$ identity matrix.

Comment: @GoodBoy: Yes, I was thinking in two dimensions. I'm not sure I follow what you want to convey by your $-I_3$ example. In any case, in arbitrary dimension, a sufficient (but definitely not necessary) condition is that $A$ has either $1$ or $-1$ as an eigenvalue (over $\mathbb{Q}$) and then it preserves a non-trivial (but degenerate) rank one form.

Comment: @GoodBoy and levap Indeed, the case of determinant -1 is wrong, $P'$ does the same to a diagonal matrix as $P$.

Comment: I will edit to remove that line.

Comment: @levap How did you get to your conclusion?

Comment: @doetoe: At this point I can show that if over the algebraic closure there is some $\lambda \neq 0$ such that $\lambda,\frac{1}{\lambda}$ are both eigenvalues of $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ then you can find an invariant quadratic form.

Comment: @doetoe:  I work with column vectors here. If $Av = \lambda v$ and $Aw = \frac{1}{\lambda} w$ for $w,v \neq 0$ then taking $G = v w^t + w v^t$ will give you a non-zero symmetric matrix which satisfies $AGA^t = G$. The matrix $G$ might have non-rational entries but the dimension of the space of solutions is the same over extension fields, so there is also a rational solution.

Comment: @levap Very nice! Combining this with Will Jagy's result this essentially settles the general case.

Answer (score 1):

There is something we can work out for determinant $-1.$ Namely, a 2 by 2 matrix of integers with determinant $-1$ is an automorphism if and only if it has trace zero.

Given $r,s,t$ integers with $r^2 + st = 1,$ but $rst \neq 0,$ we get an automorphism of 
$$ f(x,y) = x^2 + rtxy+ t^2 y^2 $$ 
with matrix identity
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 r & s \\
 t & -r \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & rt  \\
 rt & 2 t^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 r & t \\
 s & -r \\
\end{array}
\right)  =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & rt  \\
 rt & 2 t^2  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
There are other choices. Once $r^2 + st=1,$ the remaining condition on $Ax^2 + B xy + C y^2$ is just
$$ At = Br + Cs  $$

Comment: Nice one! For determinant -1 the symmetric case is pretty boring (and moreover I got a sign wrong, will edit now).